# Fluid Force on semicircular gate partially submerged

Tags: calculus

[image]

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Does the problem change since the gate is only partially submerged?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://teachers.oregon.k12.wi.us/debroux/Calc/6.7lessonkey.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple ways to set this up, but a convenient one is to start by calling the water level $ \ y = 0 \ $, measuring $ \ y \ $ "downward" from there as the "depth" variable.  The center of the circle, of which the semicircle is part, is then located at $ \ x = 0 , y = 1 \ , $ making the equation for the circle is then  $x^2 + (y-1)^2 \ = \ 2^2$.

The hydrostatic pressure at depth $y$ is given by $P(y) = \rho g y \ $.  The infinitesimal amount of force applied to the gate at that depth is then $ \ dF = P(y) \ dA = P(y) \cdot w(y) \ dy \ ,  $ where $w(y)$ is the "width function" for the gate.  We find this function by solving the equation of the circle for  $x$, and doubling that distance to the circular edge of the gate from its symmetry axis.  Thus,

$$x^2 \ = \ 4 \ - \ (y-1)^2 \ \Rightarrow \ w(y) \ = \ 2  \cdot  \sqrt{4 - (y-1)^2} $$

$$dF \ = \ \rho g y \ \cdot \ 2  \cdot  \sqrt{4 - (y-1)^2} \ dy \ ,$$

which we would then integrate "downward" in depth from $y = 0$ to $y = 1$ .

The set-up does change depending upon the water level, but we would still measure from the surface of the water as $y = 0$ in this approach.

Comment: so then we would integrate dF from 0 to 1 and p and g are just constants. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, since $ \ g \ $ is the gravitational acceleration close to Earth's surface and $ \ \rho \ $ is the volume density of water (in this problem).  The product $ \ \rho g \ $ is the _weight density_ of the water then, and so is a constant.  It will help with the integration to make a substitution $ \ u = y - 1 \ $ to simplify dealing with the radical. (You still get stuck with a trig substitution before everything is done...)

Comment: is the y in pgy not part of the integral?

Comment: Oh yes, it is part of the integrand: you can "pull out" $ \ 2 \rho g \ $ and will need to integrate $ \ \int_0^1 y \cdot \sqrt{4 - (y-1)^2} \ dy \ $ or $ \ \int_{-1}^0 (u + 1 ) \cdot \sqrt{4 - u^2} \ du \ $ .